# Java lambda - type cast of object in return statement?

Tags: java, lambda, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have following code in my spring cloud application :

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class dataflow_producer {

static SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss"); 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(dataflow_producer.class, args);

}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT)
public MessageSource<String> timerMessageSource() {       
    return ()-> new GenericMessage<String>(dateFormatter.format(new Date()));
}
}
```

My question is, how this statement works ? :

```
return ()-> new GenericMessage<String>(dateFormatter.format(new Date()));
```

Does it retype object like so ? :

```
return (MessageSource<String>)new GenericMessage<String>(dateFormatter.format(new Date()));
```

Can you explain meaning of `return ()->` ? Why is it valid in this case ? Input is `Object` of type `GenericMessage<T>`, but output is `Object` of type `MessageSource<T>` ?

Can mentioned `return` statement be rewritten to non-lambda code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Spring.

Though, in Java 8. When you got a SAM interface (Single abstract method). Called for exemple "SAMInterface".

```
public interface SAMInterface {
    void theSAMMethod();
}
```

If you need to return an object of type "SAMInterface", these code are equivalent:

```
SAMInterface toReturn = () -> println("Hello World!");
```

and

```
SAMInterface toReturn = new SAMInterface() {
    public void theSAMMethod() {
      println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

So if `MessageSource<T>` interface has exactly 1 method to redefine. 
You can use lambda :)

Comment: That was it ! I checked documentation and MessageSource<T> really has only one method 'receive'. So I created new instance of MessageSource<T> by implementhing this method. IDE warning and runtime ClassCastException error are gone. Thanks very much !